# Editing part of file matching <pattern> only in vim

Tags: vim, grep

I would like to be able to work with a long file by matching a pattern, and if possible going to the next pattern, instead of having the whole file viewable on screen.

For example suppose I have a list of entries that all start with "Name: " and I want to go through them one-by-one only viewing one at a time, and I want to "Name: " to hit the top of the screen when I go to the next entry, and the following entry starting with "Name: " to be cut off.

Comment: do you mean you have 1000lines in window, you give a pattern, `/foo`, there are 500 lines matched. you want to read the 500 line, but only one line in a window, until you pressed something, the window displays the next matched single line for you? why do you want this? what do you want to do with those matched lines? can you tell your ultimate goal?

Comment: I want to edit the entries as you normally edit in vim but with only one matching pattern showing up at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Ain't no school like the old school:

```
$ ex filename
:vim foo %
(do your editing on this line)
:cn
(more editing)
:wq
```

Use `:cp` to move to the previous matching line, `:p` to see the current line (after a command, for example).

Alternatively, you can open your file with Vim and activate a slightly more useful Ex mode with `gQ`:

```
$ vim filename
gQ
:vim foo %
(and so on)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
:g/^Name: /norm 999o
```

Then type `n` to go to the next result.

This is a hacky solution but I couldn't think of another way. It creates nine hundred and ninety nine new lines below each match. After you're done you would need to run `:g/^Name: /norm j999dd` to fix the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the behavior of search forwards/reverse to always place the match at the top of the screen.

```
:nnoremap n nzt
:nnoremap N Nzt
```

Now just search for your pattern (using `/`, `*`, etc.) and use `n` and `N` to go forwards/backwards through your results, respectively.